# TD click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to implement click event for the td:eq(6) for each row.

Below is my code:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#tblDisplayBoard tr td:eq(6)", function() {
   alert("here");
})
```

But my output is only the first row of td:eq(6) able to pop out the alert box.

Any problem to my code ?

Comment: You can `.bind` function to `.each` `(tr)` by `.find()`ing it.

Comment: @VedantTerkar bind has been deprecated since version 1.7. Use http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @LeeTaylor, Thanks for updating me. OMG what version of JQuery I'm still using then? I need to update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `:nth-child()`:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#tblDisplayBoard tr td:nth-child(6)", function() {
     alert("here");
});
```

`:eq(6)` returns the seventh (JavaScript is zero-indexed) `td` element returned by the selector.

To enable the `alert()` to appear on clicking the seventh `td` of any/every row:

```
$('#tblDisplayBoard td:nth-child(7)').on('click', function () {
    alert('here');
});
```

References:

- [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-child-pseudo).
- [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

Comment: Yes..I understand that. It able to pop out the alert box if I click on the seventh td (JavaScript is zero-indexed). My question is how able for me click on every row of seventh td and alert box is pop out..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alert for every row, you need to bind a click event to each row by using the .each() function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
var rows = $("#tblDisplayBoard tr td:eq(6)");
rows.each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert("here");
    });
});
```